# How to display StackOverflow image in conky

Tags: internet, images, conky

I want to display my StackOverflow flair on my conky. I tried downloading the image with curl and them displaying -

```
${exec curl -O https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1677096.png?theme=clean}
${image $HOME/1677096.png}
```

But it's not showing anything. It's just showing some empty space.
So how can I make it show my flair image? Image url - https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1677096.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl -O http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1677096.png?theme=clean` will write what it downloads to stdout, which isn't what you want here. Try:

```
curl -o /home/svineet/1677096.png http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1677096.png?theme=clean.
```

Comment: Also, maybe it's just me, but I would prefer to download the image via a cronjob rather than in the conkyrc. I can't give a good objective reason for this at the moment, though, other than having more flexibility in deciding how often you download the image. Conky might be updating quite regularly, which  could lead to a lot of bandwidth usage. Do you really need your SO rep to be accurate up to the second?